# Size dismatch when use multi-cuda(Dataparallel) in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm using a custom model like this

```
class SimpleNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vectors_size, features_size, hidden_size=15, dropout_rate=0.1):
        super(SimpleNN, self).__init__()
        
        self.vectors_size = vectors_size
        self.features_size = features_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate
        
        self.vectors_hidden = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(self.dropout_rate),
            nn.Linear(vectors_size, vectors_size//2),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(vectors_size//2, features_size),
            nn.Tanh()
        )
        self.hidden = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(features_size*2, hidden_size),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )
         
        self.output = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 2)
        
    def forward(self, pairs, features):
        """
        features: (n_samples, features_size)
        """
        vectors = pairs2vectors(train_pub, pairs).to(device)
        embedding_features = self.vectors_hidden(vectors)
        combined_features = torch.cat([features, embedding_features], dim=1)
        return self.output(self.hidden(combined_features))
```

This model works well when i use only one cuda, but after 'DataParallel' used like below, it always tell me the size of `features` and `embedding_features` are not match, i find that the n_samples shape of features doesn't follow my expectation just like another batch data, i dont know why and how to solve this problem.

```
    if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
            print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
            model = nn.DataParallel(model)
```

BTW, here is the pic of error message is [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNb8x.png)
Actually, for parameters `pairs` and `features` in forward method, their sizes are `(batch_size, pair)` and `(batch_size, features_size)`, and in my `train` function, code is below:

```
for batch_pairs, batch_data, batch_labels in tqdm(batch_iter(train_pairs, train_data, train_labels, train_batch_size), desc='Epoch'):
            train_iter += 1
            
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            
            batch_size = len(data)
            cum_examples += batch_size
            pred_labels = model(batch_pairs, batch_data)
            
            # Loss use torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss
            loss_func = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=weight)
            loss = loss_func(pred_labels, batch_labels)
            
            # Backpropagation
            loss.backward()
            
            # Gradient clip
            grad_norm = torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), clip_grad)
            
            # Update gradient
            optimizer.step()
```

I think my `batch_pairs` and `batch_features` have already with the batch_size, are they?

This is the [official doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#dataparallel) of `torch.nn.DataParallel`, **it says my inputs will be chunked into serveral parts to be dealt with**, in my situation it seems only `features_size` param is chunked but `pairs` not, maybe it's not a `torch.Tensor` instance? i'll have more trys and i think this mechanism is not reasonable.

I tried transform pairs into vectors outside and pass it to `forward` method but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This question is about an error in PyTorch. It has nothing to do with CUDA programming and shouldn't be tagged as such. Please do not re-add it

Comment: Ok, i doubted this issue might occur because of cuda, so i add CUDA tag.. sry, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0):

Check this,
The problem is because the batch dimension is not passed in your input data. If so,

```
 nn.DataParallel
```

might split on the wrong dimension. You have also mentioned that

```
features: (n_samples, features_size)
```

so that means batch size is not passed in the input.
Kindly add a batch dimension to your data.
For a batch size of 1, your input shape should be `[1, features]`. So for your case, it would be `[1, n_samples, features_size]`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Maybe i expressed mistakely, the `n_samples` is the batch_size, i'll add more info in my post